# How to filter django queryset with date and time?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

This is my model field

```
start = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
end = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Let's say I have value,

```
cmp_date = '2019-09-05 20:09:00'

event_exists = Event.objects.filter(start__gte=cmp_date, end__lte=cmp_date).first()
```

And in my database I have `start as "2019-09-05 18:09:00.000000" and end as "2019-09-06 19:09:00.000000"`

But this returns none.. I guess the problem is with the time? May I know how to filter with date and time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transform cmp_date to a datetime object

```
import datetime
cmp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(cmp_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and run the following:

```
event_exists = Event.objects.filter(start__lte=cmp_date, end__gte=cmp_date).first()
```

Comment: Still getting the result as `none`